# Static Reporting SaaS Solution

Tags: json, pdf, pdf-generation, reporting, saas

I am building a data entry mobile app. I am looking for a simple SaaS reporting solution. My requirements are pretty simple. Push JSON data to the service and it spits out a report in PDF format. The transformation engine would have some sort of report definition language to customize the output. Does anything of this sort exist?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's a bit more than you probably want, but with no answers for 4 months I figure a bit more work beats no answer. [Windward has a web services reporting engine.](http://www.windward.net/web-based-reporting.php) (Disclaimer - I'm the CTO.) The more effort part is we do not offer it on a SAAS model so you would have to install it on your server.

Aside from that, it is exactly what you want. Upload report templates to it. Then your app can push data to a template and get back a report. And what's really nice is you design the reports in Word, Excel, and/or PowerPoint - so no learning curve and very powerful design tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is a while later than your request, but possibly helpful. [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) has a web services interface.  It sounds like it hits your requirements (JSON, PDF, customisation).